# Не компилится прога в DevCpp. (TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Release)

Tags: c, gcc, компиляция

При попытке собрать прогу этим компилятором он выдает вот такие ошибки:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe  cannot find -lobjc"
>   "E:\ *путь к файлу* \collect2.exe   [Error] ld returned 1 exit status"

До недавнего времени все было прекрасно и он все компилил, и вот я запускаю его в очередной раз, чтобы доделать лабу и он начинает выдавать эту фигню. Гугл не помог, все что там написано это то, что может быть русский символ где-то или не подключена библиотека.
Первое отпадает т.к. все написано самостоятельно и на русский даже не переключался, а будь второе он бы и до этого выдавал эту ошибку.

Пишу на обычном С (не C++).

Comment: Там же написано - нет библиотеки `objc`. Проверьте, есть ли она. Если есть, путь до нее должен быть прописан в `-L` команды сборки или она должна находиться в стандартном пути для библиотек.

Comment: `objc` это рантайм библиотека для языка `Objective C`. В проектах С и С++ она не нужна и линковаться не должна. У вас явно какие-то кривые настройки сборки. Но какие именно - неизвестно, так как вы их не привели. Если сроки горят, то соберите проект вручную из консоли.

Comment: Подскажите тогда какие настройки сборки надо выставить? И еще раз хочу обратить внимание что в течении семестра я сдал все работы и все работало на ура а при очередном запуске он просто отказался компилить программу. Переустановка так же не помогла.

Comment: И кириллицу из путей исключить нужно. В Dev-C++ с ней проблемы.